# How to put a JButton with an image on top of another JButton with an image?

Tags: java, image, swing

So I am trying put images on to of each other and because I'm storing those images on jbuttons, I want to know if there is a way to put jbuttons on top on my already existing jbuttons. Any help please.

Edit : 
So let's say I have a
    `Jbutton b = new JButton()` and I set it an image icon.
then I have another 
`JButton x = new JButton()` and set it an image icon.

These JButtons contain two different icons. and I want the images to overlap each other. I want both images to show with the bottom button being the larger image and the button on top having a smaller size. Not sure if this is clear.

Comment: Please share what have you try? It is hard to understand what do you want.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The simplest solution is this

```
JButton j1=new JButton("a");
j1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
j1.setBackground(Color.red);
add(j1);
JButton j2=new JButton("b");
j2.setBackground(Color.yellow);
j1.add("Center", j2);
```

--

Although generally not to be used, the null layout is a solution here if you want to specify specific location and size:

```
JButton j1=new JButton("a");
j1.setLayout(null);
j1.setBackground(Color.red);
JButton j2=new JButton("b");
j2.setBackground(Color.yellow);
j2.setBounds(100, 100, 50, 50);
j1.add(j2);
add(j1);
```

Comment: thanks very much for your help. That helped me solve it. However, after adding jbuttons on each other, the 2nd jbutton is not resizable when I try to change the size. No matter what size I give it, the 2nd jbutton is always the same. Any advice on this?

Comment: (1-) for suggesting a null layout, especially when a proper solution has already been given. This will cause other problems the OP hasn't found yet.  @Kisuna97, `Any advice on this?` - yes I gave you the answer. Don't take short cuts. There is a reason short cuts don't work in the long run.

Comment: @camickr when using an OverlayLayout, how would you change the size of the child button? Using `setSize()` and `setPreferredSize()` doesn't work either.

Comment: @Kisuna97, Again the question is why? If you are adding an image to the button, then the size of the button should be the size of the image. Why are you trying to use magic numbers to manage the size of all your components?. You can give a hint to the component so it can determine its own preferred size by using `setMargin( new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20, 20) )`;

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `OverlayLayout` to stack components on top of one another.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SSCCE extends JPanel
{
    public SSCCE()
    {
        setLayout( new OverlayLayout(this) );

        JButton child = new JButton( new ImageIcon("child.jpg") );
        child.setAlignmentX(JButton.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        child.setAlignmentY(JButton.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

        JButton parent = new JButton( new ImageIcon("parent.jpg") );
        parent.setAlignmentX(JButton.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        parent.setAlignmentY(JButton.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

        add(child);
        add(parent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isOptimizedDrawingEnabled()
    {
        return false;
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new SSCCE());
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> createAndShowGUI() );
/*
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
*/
    }
}
```

Normally painting code assumes layout managers layout the components in 2 dimensions. However in this case you need to override the `isOptimizedDrawingEnabled()` method to indicate components are stacked. This makes painting a little less efficient but is needed to make sure components are painted properly.

Comment: So i must use the overlayLayout on a jpanel to do this. Because I already have board of 49 jbuttons and all I want is to overlay a few jbuttons on top of the board. to do your method, I would have to create like 49 jpanels and then overlay each panel

Comment: @Kisuna97, You could use JLabels. Set the layout of the parent to a BorderLayout and then add the child to the parent.

Comment: so your saying to use JLabels? But I don't see where this is going to where I can have like 3 components in 1 spot. But I can use something like 49 panels in a 7 by 7 and add as much components as I want by using overlayLayOut right?

Comment: @Kisuna97, I have no idea what you are doing. I gave two suggestions. If you want to use buttons then you need to use a panel with an OverlayLayout to contain the two buttons. If you don't like that idea you can use a JLabel and add another label to it so you only have two components. I can't tell you what the best solution is. You need to understand the pros and cons of each approach and make a decision.