# Put a JLabel over two JButtons

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, layout-manager, null-layout-manager

Okay so before you ask, yes I'm not using any Layout Manager. No, that doesn't make this bad design (as I've seen people in here saying because someone simply didn't use one). The thing is i want the label to always (and I mean always) show over the two buttons (over the gap left by them which makes it impossible to put it as an Icon or a text on the `JButton`).

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("ColorTap");
private void init() {

    JButton jb1 = new JButton(""), jb2 = new JButton("-");
    JLabel label = new JLabel("TEXT HERE");
    label.setForeground(Color.white);
    label.setFont(new Font("Arial Bold",Font.ITALIC,30));
    label.setBounds(60,249,200,100);
    frame.setLayout(null);
    jb1.setBounds(0, 0, 300,298);
    jb2.setBounds(0, 302, 300, 300);
    jb1.setBackground(Color.black);
    jb2.setBackground(Color.black);
    jb1.setBorderPainted(false);
    jb2.setBorderPainted(false);
    frame.add(label);
    frame.add(jb1);
    frame.add(jb2);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setSize(300, 628);
    frame.setLocation(550, 50);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

After this what's stranger to me is that the button on the bottom stays under the label and not the one on the top... HELP! Thanks

Comment: Have a look at `JLayeredPane` : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html

Comment: not using a layout manager might not be "bad" design, but it sure is masochistic ;)

Comment: "*No, that doesn't make this bad design*" That's quite a statement. This *specifically* seems like something to be handled via a layout manager. You want to lay one component over 2 other components. SOMETHING should manage this relationship, and that something would be a layout manager. It's not needed, but it would definitely be a more cohesive and modular design than what you are currently doing.

Comment: It's not really clear from your question what behaviour you're trying to get, exactly. And not using a layout manager is perhaps not 'bad design', whatever that means, but it is certainly a bad idea.

Comment: Of course it is a bad design. There is absolutely no reason NOT to use a layout manager to display the buttons in the panel. Then you use a different layout manager that allows you to stack components on top of one another. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36533728/how-to-put-a-jbutton-with-an-image-on-top-of-another-jbutton-with-an-image/36535457#36535457

Comment: What you probably want is the [setComponentZOrder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#setComponentZOrder-java.awt.Component-int-) method.  And if you don't think a null layout is bad design, ask yourself how tall the Arial Bold italic 30 pt font is, in pixels.  30 points is ³⁰⁄₇₂ inches high, which means the pixel height depends on your screen's dots-per-inch attribute.  On other people's screens, the same font will have a different height, depending on their screen's DPI.

Answer (score 0):

Swing is optimized to paint components in two dimensions. That is it assumes components will never overlap. Overlapping JButtons cause a problem because of the rollover effects which only cause the buttons to be painted, not the label, so the button is painted over the top of the label.

So you need to tell Swing that components do overlap so Swing can make sure components are painted in the proper ZOrder:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel()
{
    @Override
    public boolean isOptimizedDrawingEnabled()
    {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Now you can set the layout manager of the panel and add your components to the panel and they will be painted properly.

See: [How to put a JButton with an image on top of another JButton with an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36533728/how-to-put-a-jbutton-with-an-image-on-top-of-another-jbutton-with-an-image/36535457#36535457) for a working example that DOES use layout managers.